# Perl Cross Compilation: MAKE

Tags: perl, cross-compiling, perl-module

I've been trying to Cross Compile Perl-5.14.2 for NetBSD target from Linux machine.
Configure script successfully invoked with following options,

```
./Configure -des -Dusecrosscompile 
-Dtargetarch=netbsd 
-Dosvers=3.0.0 
-Dtargethost=10.184.22.48 
-Dtargetuser=username
-Dusrinc=.../sb1-mips/usr/include 
-Dlibpth=.../xc-sb1-mips/netbsd/Lib/lib 
-Dcc=.../mips64-netbsdelf-gcc
```

Once after Configured, `make` wasn't successful.
It breaks at different places right from creating `miniperlmain.o` file.

For example following error occurred while generating `gv.o` file:

```
gv.c: In function `Perl_try_amagic_un':
gv.c:2018: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
gv.c:2029: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
gv.c:2029: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
gv.c: In function `Perl_try_amagic_bin':
gv.c:2061: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
gv.c:2063: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
make: *** [gv.o] Error 1
```

Now to get rid of these errors I've passed two flags namely `-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` and `-DPERL_GCC_BRACE_GROUPS_FORBIDDEN` to C Compiler `CCFLAGS` which solved the problem.

- Since it is a custom build, want to know about all of the `CCFLAGS` that have to be passed in order to achieve a successful build?
- What does each flag mean?
- Is their any documentation available?

Comment: Cross compilation is something that Perl doesn't do very well. I would recommend setting up a build environment in NetBSD, and just compiling it there. Your build environment could be in a VM.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert Yes cross compiling Perl took all my time without any success. With limited availability of resources cannot build environment for NetBSD.

Comment: @BradGilbert The INSTALL document says, Perl cross compilation builds miniperl executable rather Perl. However I am able to build miniperl binary for my architecture but unable to package and transfer the Perl modules to the target machine. What might be the problem and how can I transfer the modules ?

Comment: I am not actually that knowledgeable about the Perl5 internals. If you want to discuss this further checkout the [Perl 5 Porters mailing list](http://lists.perl.org/list/perl5-porters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). It has some [OpenBSD and FreeBSD images](http://www.vagrantbox.es/). Hopefuly those will be compatible with NetBSD.

You can get a build environment very fast with that. Then you can transfer and build  your code happily :)